# Why are the two torque equations wrong together?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics, rotation

There are two torque equations :

$$\tau = I \alpha \tag{1}$$ 
$$\tau = F r \tag{2}$$

In the second equation, we imagine that $F$ is applied at $90°$, and that $I = k m r^2$. ($k$ is the constant responsible for the shape and the axis)

Then by equating those two formulas, we can get that: $$\alpha = \frac{k \omega}{t}.$$
But change in $\omega$ over time without any constant is $\alpha$ already. Why these formulas do not work together?

Comment: Hi, I got $\vec{F} \times \vec{r} = km | \vec{r} |^2 \vec{\alpha}$ from your explaination. Where did $\omega, t$ come from?

Comment: Because torque is the change in angular momentum over time. or the alpha is omega over time. so T = (I * omega) / time = I * alpha.

Comment: Did you mean the time derivative of the angular velocity vector?

Comment: Of angular momentum vector

Comment: Even so, I'm still getting $| \vec{\alpha} | = \frac{1}{kmr^2} | \vec{F} \times \vec{r} | \not\Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{k\omega}{t}$. Can you please show your derivation properly.

Comment: I*omega / t = F*r   ->   k*m*R^2 / t = m*a*R   ->  k*m*R = a  -> (Divide both sides by R) -> alpha = k*omega / t

Comment: Did you mean $I \frac{d\omega}{dt} = Fr$, invoke the 2nd law to yield $kmr^2 \frac{d\omega}{dt} = mar \Rightarrow \frac{d\omega}{dt} (= \alpha) = \frac{a}{kr}$? Please check your division and please use MathJax.

Comment: a/r is alpha, so: omega / time = alpha / k    ->    omega * k / time = alpha

Comment: (and I do not know how yo use mathJax)

Comment: If $\frac{a}{r} = \alpha$, then what I said above means that $\alpha = \frac{\alpha}{k}$, which can only be true for $k = 1$. Please be clear as to when the torque equation is valid for composite systems compared to single-particle systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108127/discussion-between-thormund-and-gameover).

Answer (score 1):

Both the equations are completely consistent with each other. Equating both the equations (assuming that $F$ is the only force acting on the body, thus we can use $F=ma$)

$$Fr=I\alpha\Longrightarrow mar=kmr^2 \alpha\Longrightarrow \boxed{a=kr\alpha}$$

This equation is true for any general body as long as there's only one force acting at a distance $r$ from the center of mass and acting perpendicular to the line joining the center of mass and the point of application of the force.

Comment: How can it be k * r * alpha? If this is a cylinder spinning around its axis then k = 0.5. So how can acceleration be the half of r *alpha?

Comment: @GameOver In a rolling cylinder, there is also friction and $F$ isn't the only force. If you would have pulled a cylinder in space (where there would be no other force), then my $kr\alpha$ will be definitely equal to $a$.

Comment: But k depends on the shape and the axis of rotation. k is the constant in moment of inertia. I do not think it is affected by weather you rotate it in vacuum or on earth. So k of any cylinder rotating around its axis will be 0.5, but the acceleration of that cylinder is not the half of its rotational acceleration times radius.

Comment: @GameOver $k$ will be the same in both the places, however the relation between $a$ and $\alpha$ will be different depending on the friction acting on the body. In the ground case (with friction), $a=r\alpha$. In the space case, $a=kr\alpha$.

Comment: Are we referring to an acceleration of a point of the object? If so, then traveled circumference is 2pi*R, and by doing some math we get that omega * R = velocity, thus the same with acceleration. So there is no k in there. If we are referring to the acceleration of a body as a whole, then the linear body acceleration in space or in air of the body is  zero, so it is also not k*R*alpha. What do I keep missing in there?

Comment: @GameOver $\omega r=v$ is only true in the case of pure rolling. Here when we apply only one force on the stationary body, pure rolling cannot happen (not until we apply the force on [the center of percussion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_percussion), which we aren't doing in our case). We would always need another force at anothe point of application so that the body starts pure rolling and then you can use $\omega r=v$ and $r\alpha =a$.

Comment: Then when can we apply a = krα? And I still don't really get to what acceleration you are referring to, because I was referring to the acceleration of a point on the object. Thank you

Comment: @GameOver Oh, there's a communication error. When I say(or said) $a$, I mean the acceleration of the center of mass, not of any particular point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108160/discussion-between-gameover-and-fakemod).